# Is this a recognised checksum algorithm?

Tags: barcode, checksum

I have to calculate a check digit for a 20-digit barcode. I have a spec which includes some pseudo code but it looks nasty. Particularly the part with division & quotient. There's plenty of scope for this to fail with loss of precision or rounding etc. I want to know if this is a recognised checksum so that I can use a tested implementation, ideally in c# or java.

Info and code:

ORIGNO; Type = String. Description: Any length barcode string excluding the check digit in the last position. Example: A 21 character Toll Connect barcode string has the check digit in the last (21st) position. Therefore the ORIGNO would be the first 20 characters of the 21 character Toll Connect barcode string.

```
PRODUCTNO = 0; type=integer
LENGTHNO = Length (ORIGNO)
MULTIPLIER=3
For LP = LENGTHNO to 1 step -1
  CHARTOCHECK=MID (ORIGNO,LP,1)
  IF isnumeric (CHARTOCHECK) then
    DIGIT = asc (CHARTOCHECK) - asc ('0')
  else
    DIGIT = rem ((asc (CHARTOCHECK)-asc ('A')) / 10)
  endif
  PRODUCTNO = PRODUCTNO + DIGIT*MULTIPLIER
  If MULTIPLIER=3 then MULTIPLIER=1 else MULTIPLIER=3 endif
end for

CHECK DIGITSTR=str (PRODUCTNO)
CHECK DIGIT=10-int (asc (right (CHECK DIGITSTR,1))-asc ('0'))
```

Note:  This algorithm could result in the Check Digit being calculated as 10. In this instance, take the right most digit, zero, as the check digit to use in the barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit like a [UPC-A](http://www.morovia.com/education/utility/upc-ean.asp) check digit calculation:

If you ignore the `IF isnumeric else` block then the loop basically performs this calculation (with `[x]` indicating digit in position `x` by starting counting from the right):

```
[1] * 3 + [2] + [3] * 3 + [4] + [5] * 3 ...
```

which is the same as `([1] + [3] + [5] + ...) * 3 + [2] + [4] + ...`

So effectively:

1. Sum up all digits in odd positions and multiply by 3
2. Sum up all digits in even positions
3. Build the sum of step 1 and 2
4. Get modulo 10 of step 3 (that what `right (CHECK DIGITSTR,1)` is basically doing)
5. Subtract the modulo of 10

which is how the UPC-A check digit is calculated (as per link above).

Now the only oddity is that UPC-A doesn't support characters - only digits as far as I'm aware - so I'm not sure why you would need to map non-digits into digit range (that's what the `else` block is doing).

Comment: Thanks Chris. This must be a modified variant of UPC-A to allow alphanumerics. A typical barcode is TNNNNAAAAAANNNNNNNNN where first AA is service code and remainder AAAA is the sender identifier. An example is T20002ATEST000001001. The barcode is printed as CODE128 format B. I have created a c# method which i'm still testing. I'm awaiting some confirmed sample barcodes from Toll before I can post my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A reference for those who need to code this (PHP code below).

re: Toll Connect, Toll Check Digit algorithm.  For 128B Barcode symbology - with 20 digit upc code string + 1 check digit = 21 digit barcode (should work on smaller barcodes as well).

```
function generate_upc_checkdigit($upc_code){
        $odd_total  = 0;
        $even_total = 0;
        for($i=1; $i<strlen($upc_code); $i++) {
            if((($i)%2) == 0) {
                /* Sum even digits */
                $even_total += $upc_code[$i];
            } else {
                /* Sum odd digits */
                $odd_total += $upc_code[$i];
            }
        }
        $sum = (3 * $odd_total) + $even_total;
        $check_digit = $sum % 10;
        return ($check_digit > 0) ? 10 - $check_digit : $check_digit;
    }
```

(Probably taken from Sameer Borate's work at [Code Diesel](http://www.codediesel.com/php/generating-upc-check-digit/))

Note: While this code is based on the previous posters comment, this code is actually different.  Toll calculates the sum on odd numbers in the upc, and this code specifically answers the question 100% correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about 2 years late, but this is the PHP function I came up with that will correctly generate a TollConnect check digit for the Toll Priority 20-digit Code128 barcode.

```
function generateTollCheckDigit($barcode){
    $productNo  = 0;
    $multiplier = 3;

    $barcodeArr = str_split(strrev($barcode));

    foreach($barcodeArr as $char){

        if(is_numeric($char)){
            $digit = $char;
        }else{
            $digit = ord(strtoupper($char)) - ord('A');
        }

        $productNo += $digit * $multiplier;

        $multiplier = $multiplier == 3 ? 1 : 3;
    }

    $checkdigit = 10 - ($productNo % 10);

    return $checkdigit == 10 ? 0 : $checkdigit;
}
```